# VBA: Send multiple emails with .jpg in body and tabel as an attachment

Tags: excel, vba, performance, outlook

I am trying to get the personalized message working. I have difficulty in sending multiple emails via VBA with simultaneous embedded photo in email body and attachment.

Here is my "mapping" for emails.

A (col)  B   C   D          E                           F           G         H         I      J
Client   TO  CC Subject Body part 1/5 <.png/.jpg>   part 2/5   part 3/5   part 4/5  part 5/5 full body

compact body:

(E

'here supposed to be photo

=F2&"

"&G2&"

"&H2&"

"&I2&"")

```
K
```

attachment '(execel file)

Body text consists of data from other file with macros, which I can't change (that's the biggest problem). My macro creates multiple emails with attachments but I cannot figure it out how to add photo in body. I found sth like that:

> .Attachments.Add "C:.jpg"
> .HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:logo.jpg'" & "" & _vba

But it didn't work in many emails...
Looking for any feedback from You guys :) Maybe some of You created similar code?

my code:

```
Sub mergeMailing()

Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim OA As Object

Dim msg As Object

Dim i As Integer

Dim last_row As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Merge mailing")

Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To last_row

Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

msg.to = sh.Range("B" & i).Value

msg.cc = sh.Range("C" & i).Value

msg.Subject = sh.Range("D" & i).Value

msg.Body = sh.Range("E" & i).Value

'place for .jpg/.png

msg.Body = sh.Range("I" & i).Value

msg.Attachments.Add sh.Range("J" & i).Value

msg.display

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think we found a sender of all those badly merged emails starting with "Dear ," (it's `Dear`, `space`, `comma`)